# why my "posts edited" count decrements?

Tags: support, editing

My question is related to "Activity Profile". 
And particularly for "posts edited" (Total number of edits made to improve existing posts).

[image]

I observed from few days that my count of "posts edited" is decremented from 403 to 401 and today it is showing 399.
From which calculations this count is decided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the tooltip, it's:

> Total number of edits made to improve existing posts

which is a little misleading, since [there are exceptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138232/145982). But in your case I suspect it's the "existing posts" part that's relevant; you edited posts that ended up getting deleted. That figure counts the number of non-deleted posts by other people where you made a substantive (non-retagging) edit